# html form submit issue

Tags: html, form-submit

I have finished my site but my issue is when I tried to submit a contact to see if it works, I keep getting the error " Cannot GET /bojurier@gmail.com ".  I was hoping some can help me with what I'm doing wrong.

I have tried changing the input into a button but it still gave me an error.

```
<form class="form-wrap" action="bojurier@gmail.com" method="Get" enctype="text/plain">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Name">
  <input type="email" placeholder="Email">
  <textarea placeholder="Message" name="Message"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send">  
</form>
```

The error message below is what I keep on getting.

> Cannot GET /bojurier@gmail.com

Comment: `action="bojurier@gmail.com"` is not valid, what do you expect this to do?

Comment: You need to pass a path in your `action`. You have passed an email.

Comment: Action attribute in forms are meant to pass the data to a particular method on back-end on form submit event. It's your job that in that method you write the logic to send the form data to your email address.

Comment: What I'm trying to accomplish is to make it so that when the submit button is pushed, I would like that information to be sent to my email. which is why I put my email address in the action perimeter. Any idea of how to go about that using HTML?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your action to mailto:

```
<form class="form-wrap" action="mailto:bojurier@gmail.com" method="Get" 
enctype="text/plain">
```

Answer (score 1):

Method should be post. Will receive these details.  Method='post' and action="mailto:you@yourdmainhere.com it will work.

Comment: Thank you it works perfectly now. I really appreciate your help.